# How to order by values from nested multisets?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

An [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69552492/jooq-multiset-order-result-set-via-conditions-on-multiset) covers how to use jOOQ's `MULTISET_AGG` feature to order a query based on an aggregate function over a nested collection: use `GROUP BY` to group the query by all the selected columns from the parent table, rather than trying to exploit implementation details of `MULTISET`.

Is there an approach that works with multi-level collections? I'm using PostgreSQL but obviously if there's an engine-independent way to do it, even better.

For example, if I have a nested query using `MULTISET`:

```java
var results =
    create
        .select(
            ORGANIZATIONS.ID,
            ORGANIZATIONS.NAME,
            multiset(
                    select(
                        DEPARTMENTS.ID,
                        DEPARTMENTS.NAME,
                        multiset(
                            select(EMPLOYEES.ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, EMPLOYEES.NAME)
                                .from(EMPLOYEES)
                                .where(EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID.eq(DEPARTMENTS.ID)))))
                .from(DEPARTMENTS)
                .where(DEPARTMENTS.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(ORGANIZATIONS.ID)))
        .from(ORGANIZATIONS)
        .fetch();
```

I can easily sort each department's employees by salary if I put an `ORDER BY` in the innermost query.

```java
                        multiset(
                            select(EMPLOYEES.ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, EMPLOYEES.NAME)
                                .from(EMPLOYEES)
                                .where(EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID.eq(DEPARTMENTS.ID))
                                .orderBy(EMPLOYEES.SALARY.desc()))))
```

But how do I also sort the list of departments by the highest employee salary, and the list of organizations by the highest employee salary across its departments?

Changing the `MULTISET`s into `MULTISET_AGG`s and only doing the `ORDER BY` on the top level of the query, as in the earlier question with just one level of nesting, seems like it can't work here because you'd need to group by two different sets of columns at the same time, and also because you can't nest aggregate functions (at least on PostgreSQL.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a simple way to aggregate these sums without accessing some tables twice. If I do, I'll update this answer. But here's a solution that answers your question:

```java
var results = create
    .select(
        ORGANIZATIONS.ID,
        ORGANIZATIONS.NAME,
        multiset(
            select(
                DEPARTMENTS.ID,
                DEPARTMENTS.NAME,

                // Employees per department sorted by salary
                multisetAgg(EMPLOYEES.ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, EMPLOYEES.NAME)
                    .orderBy(EMPLOYEES.SALARY.desc()))
           .from(DEPARTMENTS)
           .leftJoin(EMPLOYEES)
               .on(EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID.eq(DEPARTMENTS.ID))
           .where(DEPARTMENTS.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(ORGANIZATIONS.ID))
           .groupBy(DEPARTMENTS.ID, DEPARTMENTS.NAME)

           // Departments sorted by max employee salary
           .orderBy(max(EMPLOYEES.SALARY).desc()))
    .from(ORGANIZATIONS)

    // Organisations sorted by max employee salary via extra join
    .orderBy(field(
        select(max(EMPLOYEES.SALARY))
        .from(EMPLOYEES)
        .where(EMPLOYEES.departments().ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(ORGANIZATION.ID))
    ).desc())
    .fetch();
```

Another solution would be to sort the outer result only after querying:

```java
var results = create
    .select(
        ORGANIZATIONS.ID,
        ORGANIZATIONS.NAME,
        multiset(
            select(
                DEPARTMENTS.ID,
                DEPARTMENTS.NAME,
                multisetAgg(EMPLOYEES.ID, EMPLOYEES.SALARY, EMPLOYEES.NAME)
                    .orderBy(EMPLOYEES.SALARY.desc()),
                max(EMPLOYEES.SALARY))
           .from(DEPARTMENTS)
           .leftJoin(EMPLOYEES)
               .on(EMPLOYEES.DEPARTMENT_ID.eq(DEPARTMENTS.ID))
           .where(DEPARTMENTS.ORGANIZATION_ID.eq(ORGANIZATIONS.ID))
           .groupBy(DEPARTMENTS.ID, DEPARTMENTS.NAME)
           .orderBy(max(EMPLOYEES.SALARY).desc()))
    .from(ORGANIZATIONS)
    .fetch()
    .sortDesc(Comparator.comparing(
        // r.value3() is the outer multiset()
        r -> r.value3().isEmpty() 
           ? 0 

        // r.value3().get(0).value4() is the top max(EMPLOYEES.SALARY) value
           : r.value3().get(0).value4()
    ));
```

It would be possible to define a new operator that extracts a value again from a `MULTISET`, without depending on its SQL/XML or SQL/JSON serialisation implemetation. Or, you could roll your own using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), knowing what the serialisation implementation looks like (knowing that it might change subtly, in the future)

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, I am the guy who filed [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12517) though I goofed by simplifying the example there to a single level of nesting. I bring that up just to point out the workaround there using lateral joins, but, as you say, that approach ends up needing to extract the values based on knowing the implementation.